# What happens to elementary OS if Ubuntu discontinues its Desktop?

Tags: server, elementary

I've read several articles claiming that Ubuntu may stop developing its Desktop version in favor of focusing solely server editions. In a scenario like this, what becomes of elementary OS and other similar operating systems, which are based on Ubuntu?

Example article:
http://fossforce.com/2017/04/future-desktop-ubuntu/

Comment: This is off-topic, but however I can say these 1) Ubuntu desktop isn't discontinuing 2) elementary OS doesn't depend  on Unity, which is discontinuing in Ubuntu actually

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Canonical is not going to stop making the desktop version. They are no longer going to be spending money on Unity and convergence. All this means for the end user is that future versions of Ubuntu will be gnome (as well as the other official flavors) there will just be no more of the Unity DE.

See this article from mark shuttleworth (Founder of canonical) specifically paragraph 2. 
https://insights.ubuntu.com/2017/04/05/growing-ubuntu-for-cloud-and-iot-rather-than-phone-and-convergence/

Comment: And Elementary doesn't depend on Unity